# Does the 90/180 rule still apply after obtaining a visa?

Tags: visas, residency, romania, 90-180-visa-rules

I am from Egypt, went to Romania on a German residence, stayed there for 80 straight days, and I went back to Egypt.

Does obtaining a long term visa to Romania make me able to travel back to Romania before the 180 day mark, or do I have to wait it out before traveling?

Comment: If you have a Romanian **National Visa** (Type D), the Romanian 90 day rule does not count.

Answer (score 1):

You can return to Romania at any point with a Romanian long-stay (type D) visa because the 90/180 rule does not apply to long-stay visas.

However, in no case do you need to wait 180 days before returning.  With short-stay authorization (a type C visa or visa exemption), you can of course return for ten days if you return within 90 days of your departure.  *You can return for 90 days after being away for 91 or more days.*